# Get xml node using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a request that returns a large xml file. I have the file in a XmlDocument type in my application. From that Doc how can I read an element like this:

```
<gphoto:videostatus>final</gphoto:videostatus>
```

I would like to pull that value final from that element. Also If i have multiple elements as well, can I pull that into a list? thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is that all you want from the XML file?  Just the `gphoto:videostatus` elements?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Yes thats one thing I want. And also I also want to pull out a list of elements with the same "element name" such as <link>link1</link><link>link2></link>

Comment: @gideon i have not tried much. I am searching the web right now for info.

Comment: Obviously, your XML has **XML namespaces** (`gphoto`) defined - you need to check out the [`XmlNamespaceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) on how to define XML namespace to parse your XML document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have an XmlDocument then you can use the function GetElementsByTagName() to create an XmlNodeList that can be accessed similar to an array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk.aspx

```
//Create the XmlDocument.
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("books.xml");

//Display all the book titles.
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
for (int i=0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{   
  Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select nodes using XPath and SelectSingleNode SelectNodes.  Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C for examples. Then you can use for example InnerText to get final. Maybe you need to work with namespaces (gphoto). The `//videostatus` would select all videostatus elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try using LINQ

```
        XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get(""); //use the xmnls namespace here
        XElement element = XElement.Load(""); // xml file path
        var result = element.Descendants(ns + "videostatus")
                     .Select(o =>o.Value).ToList();

       foreach(var values in value)
       {

       }
```

Thanks

Deepu